# SELECT with added IDENTITY column

Tags: sql-server-ce

Just A Quick Question. Checked Many sites to no avail! I need stack help!

SQL Compact Edition!

have a query:

```
SELECT w.url
FROM Company c, Website w, Users u
WHERE w.companyID = c.companyID AND c.userID = u.userID AND u.userID = 23
ORDER BY w.url ASC;
```

I know its not the best query, but basically this returns a list of websites where the userID is 23. It returns a list like:

```
URL
-----------------
facebook.com
stackoverflow.com
google.com
...
etc
```

However i would like the add a column in the SELECT statement. so my results would appear like:

```
URL               | ID
------------------|---------
facebook.com      | 1
stackoverflow.com | 2
google.com        | 3
...               | ...
etc               | onward
```

Ive tried many methods including sub queries and stuff but I'm using SQL CE! and is doesn't like running when I put an "=" when I select my columns.

I think its a simple solution but I CANT DO IT :(

Ive tried

```
SELECT w.url, count(*) as id
SELECT w.url, IDENTITY as id
```

and multiple variations of that!

EDIT: I want the id to increment from 1 to however many records there are regarless of records returns or order or what ever!

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: Why not add an Id to `Websites` ?

Comment: Websites does have an ID, but i want the id column to run from 1 to how many records there are no matter what records are returned!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.url, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY w.url ASC)
FROM Company c, Website w, Users u
WHERE w.companyID = c.companyID AND c.userID = u.userID AND u.userID = 23
```

Comment: the OVER keyword is not supported I don't think :s well that's the error that occurs. Unless its the ROW_NUMBER() thats not supported

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch, Ah, I just noticed you've tagged the question Sql-CE.. and I do not believe that supports ROW_NUMBER()...  My apologies.